# From angular how to call the backend api integrated with keycloak?

Tags: angular, keycloak-rest-api

[This is the error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qlLv.png)

[I have used proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/878KZ.png)

[my service class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86EpG.png)

The url which I want to call at the backend is http://localhost:8089/greet

Actually, what I am trying to do is integrating keycloak with backend and calling that from front end. at first when I try to open my web application it should redirect me to keycloak login page from which the user role should be verified and call the respective api.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Currently your api calls are going to frontend url i.e, `localhost:4300`, try to enter complete path of api in your get method `'http://localhost:8089/api/greet'` instead of `'/api/greet'`.

Comment: If I give 'http://localhost:8089/api/greet', still I am getting error

Comment: Is it same error?